# jQuery click function not working with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval

I'm calling an internal web page to my div every second with setInterval (that is to say reloading div). It's working fine but users should click a button inside of that reloading div and it fails.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<ul class="folio-list" id="buttons"></ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      setInterval(function(){ $("#buttons").load("<?php echo site_url('buttons'); ?>"); }, 1000);
    };
    </script>
```

And this is the calling page's HTML:

```
<li class="tile-large pink">
            <div id="time">
              <h2 class="Hours">30 Minutes </br> 1 BTC</h2>
                <br />
              <div class="timer">
                  <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hrs" value="0">
                      <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hrs</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                   <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mnt" value="0">
                      <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Mnt</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                   <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sec" value="0">
                      <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sec</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

              </div>
              <br />
              <h3 class="winner-name"> Nobody </h3>
              <button class="btn btn-success pay" data-id="2">Get Ticket!</button>
            </div>


        </li>
```

I'm trying to make this part clickable

```
<button class="btn btn-success pay" data-id="2">Get Ticket!</button>
```

with this JavaScript code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.pay').click(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   $.ajax({
     url: "<?php echo site_url('pay'); ?>" + "/" + id,
     type: 'POST',
     success: function(answer) {
             $('#answer').html(answer);
         }
   });
 });
 </script>
```

When I disable reloading thing, button working fine. I'm sure that the problem is setInterval part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use a delegated event handler as the `.pay` element is dynamically added to the page after each refresh. See the question I marked as duplicate for more information

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan I read it but I'm not good with JavaScript and couldn't handle. Can you help me?

Comment: Ah, I made it. Thank you.